# Android highlight circle in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design

[Samsung Health Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VBib.jpg)

I'm making a bar chart that shows a bar and a date using a recycler view that scrolls horizontally. And I'm wondering how I can create something like the black highlight circle in Samsung health?

I thought of setting a background for the date and set the background visible only when the item is in the center of the screen, but I found the Samsung's black circle doesn't just show up or disappear with the date as shown in the picture. How did it achieve the effect to change the part of the color of the date when it is overlapping with the circle?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is one quick way of doing it using `PotterDuff` [CLEAR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode#CLEAR) mode. When you are drawing date text on top of black circle. Use clear mode to change the color of the overlapped text and use `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE,null);` while initializing your custom view.

You can learn about PotterDuff [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. PotterDuff is sure something new to learn. However, it doesn't work for this case, since the text is not drawn with any special way. It is just TextView. When I have a drawable over a textView, there is no way to let the drawable know that the text underneath is what it should overlap with. The structure is like this: Recycler view on the botton, drawable on the top. Some textViews in the recycler view. It looks like Sumsung's implementation is through their framework, and it's not Plain Java elements.